# Not able to get full 100 test case in Google code jam.My Output case Generate only two case instead of 100

Tags: java

[INPUT FILE LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0bywFDvx82hZnlnX3NpZlh1aTQ)

I am trying to solve Google Apac past Questions ,i have read an input from the file the no.of test cases are 100,but it only generate 2 output cases,Can any one help?
Trying to solve from last week but does'nt able to get required output file.
The code is posted below,Any help will be highly appreciated
Thank you

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Jam
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

Scanner sc = new Scanner(new 
FileReader("C:/Users/AAKASH/eclipse/Downloads/A-small-practice-1.in"));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new 
FileWriter("C:/Users/AAKASH/eclipse/Downloads/A-small-practice-1.out"));

HashSet<String>hset=new HashSet<String>();
int T=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
{

int M=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

if(M>=1&&M<=10)
{
int d=2*M;
String Name[]=new String[d];
for(int j=0;j<d;j++)
{
Name[j]=sc.next();
hset.add(Name[j]);
}

if(hset.size()<Name.length)
{
pw.println("Case #"+i+":"+" "+"NO");
}
if(hset.size()==Name.length)
{
pw.println("Case #"+i+":"+" "+"YES");
}
}
}
pw.flush();
pw.close();
sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Whats there in input file? We will be requiring that to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You should invest a bit more. You dump some code contest name, some code, and now what? We figure the problem, debug the code and tell you the solution? Hint: the idea of such contests is that YOU sit down and work and work to solve it. Meaning: you even were too lazy to properly indent your source code. Reduces my motivation to help dramatically.

Comment: @NisheshPratap just posting

Comment: @NisheshPratap posted a link for input file

Comment: As I don't know about the question, please confirm what should be the expected output for first three test cases.

Comment: it will be NO for all 3 cases means @NisheshPratap

Comment: means Case #1 NO Case #2 NO Case #3 NO

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your main method, now it is generating result for all test cases but you need to verify the logic and output.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:/A-small-practice-1.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:/A-small-practice-1.out"));

        HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();
        int T = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());
        for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
            String str = sc.nextLine().trim();
            int M = Integer.parseInt(str);

            if (M >= 1 && M <= 10) {
                int d = 2 * M;
                String Name[] = new String[d];
                for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                    Name[j] = sc.next();
                    hset.add(Name[j]);
                }

                if (hset.size() == Name.length) {
                    pw.println("Case #" + i + ":" + " " + "YES");
                } else {
                    pw.println("Case #" + i + ":" + " " + "NO");
                }
            }
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        sc.close();
    }
```

Comment: thanx sir @Nishesh Pratap